# How to Retrieve an Iconized Program from the Tray with a Keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, system-tray, wmctrl, electron

I know that many here don't love Electron, but it's here to stay, as many commercial solution providers are using to package the web applications and make them act/feel like desktop apps and have them work cross-platform. I use multiple messaging platforms for work (e.g. Slack, WhatsApp, PulseSMS, etc..). In the case of Slack, their desktop app is Electron-based. I have been using Franz as a means of corraling all of these into a single app that sits in my tray. Franz works well.

Something changed regarding Electron (and the resultant implementations by the messaging providers) whereby the app (whether Slack itself, or Slack via Franz) requires multiple clicks to retrieve from the tray, with no keyboard shortcut available to wake it up and bring it into focus. I suppose that this is not real big deal, but I do find it annoying. There is some discussion in Franz' Git repo of regressing to an earlier version, but it seems that something like wmctrl or similar might be able to do this, but I don't know how.

I am wondering if anyone can advise on a way of reducing the clicks and also assigning a keyboard shortcut that streamlines this:

Right now, I click on the Franz icon (or if Slack outside of Franz, Slack), which reveals "Show Franz." Then click

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Workaround***

If the position of the Icon on Dash is fixed, you can do this with `xdotool`

for example:
I am using Dash-to-Panel extension. I have `gnome-tweaks` fixed in my Dash at position 4.
So it can be opened with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> Key Press.

I can achieve this key pressings automation with `xdotool` with command `xdotool key Super_L+4`

[image]

like this you can make your 1st clik either with mouse location to already known position of your Icon on Dash or with shortcut keys like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

Ok, I have successfully opened `gnome-tweaks` now I need to close the window automatically, i need a mouse movement and mouse click.

so the command I used is `xdotool key Super_L+4 mousemove 1112 57 sleep 5 click 1`

[image]

I guess your Icon Position and "Show Franz" Position are fixed.
first get the mouse positions and then create a shortcut to run xdotool command.

[image]

**Downside:** Based on trails, xdotool sleep 1 or may be lower values are required while creating a custom shortcut.

Comment: I'm using Cinnamon, but your approach seems like it would work except for the issue that I think I need two clicks to launch 1) Click on tray icon x:2239 y: 1416 2) Select the Show Franz option x:2239 y:1343

Comment: so did you run from terminal `xdotool mousemove 2239 1416 click 1 sleep 1 mousemove 2239 1343 click 1`? i think you need to trail and see by adding sleep values.. this sleep value is a downside but better than physical hand movement click and time.

Comment: Love it. It worked; however, the issue is going to be that the location of that tray icon seems to fluctuate. Also, if I change resolutions or displays the coordinates will be off.